# Does Mono\Xamarin support Basic auth?

Tags: c#, mono

I'm trying to run this code with Xamarin.Android but it falls down on last line(System.Net.WebException: There was an error on processing web request: Status code 401(Unauthorized)):

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
var endPointUri = new Uri(@"http://192.168.1.241/edo/Euphrates.svc/ILogonService-Basic");
var factory = new ChannelFactory<ILogonService>(binding, new EndpointAddress(endPointUri));
factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "test";
ILogonService service = factory.CreateChannel();
Console.WriteLine(service.Logon("test"));
```

On windows console app everything works very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic authentication in an url in Xamarin:

https://username:password@www.example.com/webcallback?foo=bar